# Will the "worst case scenario" work for all pigeon hole questions?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

I am looking for a generalized method to solve simple to advanced pigeonhole principle questions (that are PURELY pigeon-hole ie not in combination with any other topics like probability)

The definition:

> Suppose that $n$ pigeons fly into $d$ pigeonholes. Performing the division, let $n = qd + r$, where the remainder is $r = 0, 1, 2, . . . , d − 1.$

> If $r = 0$, there must be at least one pigeonhole with $q$ pigeons.

> If $r > 0$, there must be at least one pigeonhole with $q + 1$ pigeons.

> The least number of pigeons that will guarantee that there is at least one pigeonhole with at least
> $q + 1$ pigeons is $qd + 1$

Normally I don't use the above definition because I dont really understand it but I can solve wuestion anyway by intuition. So I am asking: If $r=0$, why is $n = q$ and not $qp$? If $r > 0$, why is the remainder $q+1$? Since the remainder can be up to $d-1$, I don't understand where the $q+1$ comes from. And From the third statement, I have realised that I am probably interpreting the law incorrectly: it seems that I should be ignoring $d$ for some reason or maybe I am just supposed to set it equal to $1$?

My second question is: will considering the "worst case scenario" work for every question? This method has not failed me yet but if I search online, there is hardly any information on it (and on the PHP in general).

Typical questions involve something along the lines of "how many socks/ties/hats would I have to pick to ensure two of the same color" and I just consider the worst case scenario where I delay the desired outcome until the very end. Then I just add one to force the ceiling function to go to the next positive integer, which basically ensures the "same color" pair. HOWEVER, when the "worst case scenario" gets more abstract eg $$\text{Prove by using PHP that there are two powers of $2$ that differ by a multiple of 8479}$$

I cannot identify the worst case scenario. Basically,should I be able to use it in all PHP questions?

I have a statement which I think is what I need to prove:

RTP $2^a - 2^b = 8479k$, where $a,b,k$ are integers.

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here USING MY METHOD. I know there is another method that consists of considering a set of powers of $2$ and dividing by $8480$ to produce $8479$ remainders. But in this case, is there a "worst case scenario"?

Comment: What are "pigeonhole principle questions"? Out there in the wild, mathematical problems do not come with a label stating the method of proof. if your question is too general, it is hard for us to help you with it.

Comment: Pigeonhole principle questions are questions that use the pigeonhole principle. I am asking whether the "sub method" of considering the worst-case scenario will work in this question. I edited the proof to state that PHP must be used (I forgot to add that in the original question)

Comment: "If $r>0$, why is the remainder $q+1$?": the quoted section doesn't say that the remainder is $q+1$. What does it say?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "why is the number of pigeons $q+1$"? Would it not be $n = qd + 1$? I am just confused how $q+1$ was obtained if $r>0$

Comment: That's the total number of pigeons. It isn't the number you would expect to find in one of the pigeonholes. Incidentally your statement of the definition should have the words "at least" attached to the number of pigeons also.

Comment: I think I am just confused as to why the $d$ dissapears

Answer (score 4):

The version of pigeonhole principle that you cited is ridiculous. Not because it is wrong, but because it is **NOT** the right way to learn at all. In fact, it is completely pointless to learn the name "pigeonhole principle". Instead, just think as follows:

If you have $d$ groups, each having at most $k$ objects, then in total you have at most $d·k$ objects. **That is it.** Now think what this implies for the applications you want.

No need for your vague intuition about 'worst-case scenario' either. If every power of two is different modulo $m$, then obviously there are at most $m$ powers of two.......

Comment: By the way, you need *exactly* this correct way of thinking when you think about the generalization to set theory or measure theory. These are not at your current level, but I bet you will recall what I say here when you see it. For set theory, a countable union of countable sets is countable, and in general a union of $κ$ sets each of cardinality at most $λ$ has cardinality at most $κ·λ$. For measure theory, the total measure of $n$ sets each of measure at most $c$ is at most $n·c$, and this applies to (lebesgue) integrals of indicator functions for those sets.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I agree that this definition is impractical - I only sought to understand it because I thought it would've revealed an insight to me but I will just stick to common sense. WHat about the second part of my question, will the worst cases scenario method work for my proof?

Comment: @user71207: You can recover the version in your post from the correct way of thinking. Note that the floor/ceil that appears would be simply a consequence of the discrete possible values, and not due to the intrinsic bound itself. If you put $n$ balls into $d$ boxes, they clearly can have up to $\lceil n/d \rceil$ balls each (by dividing as evenly as possible), but cannot all have less than that (otherwise total is at most $(\lceil n/d \rceil - 1)·d < (n/d) · d = n$). The reason I said not to use "worst-case scenario" thinking is that you can't make that precise without doing what I did.